# Does CMake find_path / find_library search for <PackageName>_ROOT by default?

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

Upon reading about CMake policy 74 - https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0074.html

> [...] now searches prefixes specified by the _ROOT CMake variable and the *ROOT environment variable. Package roots are maintained as a stack so nested calls to all find** commands inside find modules and config packages also search the roots as prefixes.

Does this mean `<PackageName>_ROOT` need not be included in the `find_*` paths explicitly?
Does this mean `<PackageName>_ROOT` will be checked automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but this only applies to CMake 3.12 and greater, as stated in the policy [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0074.html#policy:CMP0074):

> In CMake 3.12 and above the `find_package(<PackageName>)` command now searches prefixes specified by the `<PackageName>_ROOT` CMake variable and the `<PackageName>_ROOT` environment variable.

This **also** only applies to `find_*` commands within find modules and config packages.

This behavior is stated explicitly in the documentation for *all* of the `find_*` commands. For example, here is a snippet from the [`find_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) documentation (important section bolded):

> If `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` is not specified, the search process is as follows:
>
> 1. If called from within a find module or any other script loaded by a call to `find_package(<PackageName>)`, search prefixes unique to the current package being found. **Specifically, look in the `<PackageName>_ROOT` CMake variable and the `<PackageName>_ROOT` environment variable.** The package root variables are maintained as a stack, so if called from nested find modules or config packages, root paths from the parent’s find module or config package will be searched after paths from the current module or package. In other words, the search order would be `<CurrentPackage>_ROOT`, `ENV{<CurrentPackage>_ROOT}`, `<ParentPackage>_ROOT`, `ENV{<ParentPackage>_ROOT}`, etc. This can be skipped if `NO_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH` is passed or by setting the `CMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH` to `FALSE`.

Also note, the `<PackageName>_ROOT` variable will *not* be used for the search if the find module is called with `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` or `NO_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH`.